# How to burn subtitles into video with FFMPEG.wasm?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

In a react project, with node v.16+, and `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` v0.10.1 and `@ffmpeg/core` v0.10.0

Im trying to burn subtitles into an .mp4, in-browser.

the command used was:

`` await ffmpeg.current.run('-i', 'test-input.mp4', '-vf', `subtitles=testSRT.srt`, 'test-output-2.mp4'); ``

the ffmpeg configuration info is

> configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --enable-cross-compile
> --disable-x86asm --disable-inline-asm --disable-stripping --disable-programs --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-autodetect --extra-cflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3 --closure 1'
> --extra-cxxflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3 --closure 1' --extra-ldflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3
> --closure 1 -L/src/build/lib' --pkg-config-flags=--static --nm=llvm-nm --ar=emar --ranlib=emranlib --cc=emcc --cxx=em++ --objcc=emcc --dep-cc=emcc --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-zlib --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus --enable-libwebp --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi

the way i set the core package is like so:

```
ffmpeg.current = createFFmpeg({
  corePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js',
  log: true
})
```

so this build is configured with `libass` as you can see in the config info, so it shouldnt have a problem with subtitling. but im getting an error related to the font, which i never explicitly set. this is the only error output related to subtitling

`[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x2134b80] can't find selected font provider`

`[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x3764100] fontselect: failed to find any fallback for font: (Arial, 400, 0)`

so the video is output to the set location, but theres no subtitles on the video. i assume because there was some error with the font, even though none was set. one other thing i tried to do was add a .ttf file to the project in `assets/fonts/` and explicitly set the `fontsdir` value in the filter, but it seemed to have the same issues as well, heres that example:

`` await ffmpeg.current.run('-i', 'test-input.mp4', '-vf', `subtitles=testSRT.srt: fontsdir=../assets/fonts: force_style='Arial'`, 'test-output-2.mp4'); ``

Answer (score 0):

With @ffmpeg/ffmpeg the fonts need to be loaded:

```
  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', assFile, await fetchFile(assFileUrl));
  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'tmp/Arimo', await fetchFile('../../pathToFile'));
  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', inputName, await fetchFile(fileUrl));

  const burnCalls: string[] = [
    '-i',
    `${inputName}`,
    '-vf',
    `subtitles=${assFile}:fontsdir=/tmp:force_style='Fontname=Arimo,Fontsize=24,PrimaryColour=&H00FFFFFF,OutlineColour=&H000000FF,BackColour=&H00000000,Bold=1,Italic=0,Alignment=2,MarginV=40'`,
    outputName,
  ];

  await ffmpeg.run(...burnCalls);
```

It is important to note that naming convention of fontsdir must be tmp/[FontName] and then read as fontsdir=/tmp .

Also, when you put the force_style='Fontname=[FontName]' make sure this is the FontName that can be found by CTRL clicking on the file and seeing get info -> Full name (on mac).